# detailTextLabel does not update in ios 8 swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a simple table view that uses UITableViewController with the Subtitle style. I am unable to update the detailTextView field successfully. I have read on Stack Overflow that there is a potential bug in ios 8 but none of the suggested workarounds worked for me. When I print the value of the field I get nil. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code below followed by the results of the println statements. I have seen another SO entry listing this a bug in ios 8 but none of the suggested workarounds worked for me. I have also filed question this on Apple Forum

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!UITableViewCell
    let xrow = indexPath.row
    let xsection = indexPath.section
    //if (xrow == 0) && (xsection == 0)  {
        // initializing with hard values initially
        cell.textLabel?.text = "initial"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Initial"
    //}

    println("row = \(xrow), section = \(xsection)")
    println("0: cell.textLabel?.text = \(cell.textLabel?.text)")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Section = \(xsection)"
    println("1: cell.textLabel?.text = \(cell.textLabel?.text)")
    println("0: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = \(cell.detailTextLabel?.text)")
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ("section = \(xsection), row = \(xrow)") as String!
    println("1: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = \(cell.detailTextLabel?.text)")
    return cell
}

}


row = 0, section = 0
0: cell.textLabel?.text = Optional("initial")
1: cell.textLabel?.text = Optional("Section = 0")
0: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
1: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
row = 1, section = 0
0: cell.textLabel?.text = Optional("initial")
1: cell.textLabel?.text = Optional("Section = 0")
0: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
1: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
row = 2, section = 0
0: cell.textLabel?.text = Optional("initial")
1: cell.textLabel?.text = Optional("Section = 0")
0: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
1: cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `detailTextLabel` always return `nil`, if the cell style does not support.

[UITableViewCell detailTextLabel reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/detailTextLabel)

So change

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!UITableViewCell
```

to

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell
if cell == nil{
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked except I had to eliminate the check for nil. I don't fully understand the dynamics of cell creation. I also don't understand why setting the style to Subtitle in Interface Builder does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a default cell's detailTextLabel in quite a while. The docs for that field say:

> detailTextLabel: Holds the secondary (or detail) label of the cell.
>   UITableViewCell adds an appropriate label when you create the cell in
>   a style that supports secondary labels. If the style doesn’t support
>   detail labels, nil is returned. See UITableViewCellStyle for
>   descriptions of the main label in currently defined cell styles.

You are not specifying a cell style. I'm guessing that detailTextLabel is nil. Log just detailTextLabel to check.

Comment: As I explained in a previous comment I had specified Subtitle as the style in Interface Builder and it is not clear to me why it was ignored by Swift even though the source of the IB did have the Style in it. As you correctly surmised the value was nil. I set the style in code as suggested by nRewik and that resolved the problem.